# How do I write an ionic alert component once for the entire application?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, alert, overlay, popover

This is an design-approach question.  I don't (yet) have broken code.  ;-)

I have a firestore connected ionic/angular app with multiple modules.  Users frequently move from page-to-page/module to module throughout usage.

Another part of my system drops new elements into the Firestore database in response to external events.  I want to generate a new message on the screen whenever a new entry appears in the Firestore database regardless of which module/page is currently being presented to the user..

It seems from my research that I have to create an alert or popover or overlay component, and then include that component in every module and place it in every template file in order for the message to appear.  There doesn't seem to be a way to write an overlay component that will shove itself over whatever else is being presented whenever there is an appropriate trigger.

**Is there a way implement an overlay/alert/popover once at the app level without writing code to handle a potential overlay/popover/alert in every module?**

--Paul

Comment: i don't know if I understood correctly but u say u got a place to handle the events received from firestore so why don't u trigger your alert once u receive the event... what is the point of adding the alert on each page though u are only recieving it in one place? hope i understood what u said and i'm not wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could make use of snackbar as a service. Configure the styling of the modal, pass in data for the modal (custom messages etc). https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/examples

MatSnackBar is an angular directive that’s used for showing a notification bar specifically on the mobile devices.
These types of UI components are generally used several times.
So to avoid the repetition of code, a service can simply be created to use SnackBar in different components.

To create a service you have to use the following command:
ng g s snackBar
Now import MatSnackBar from @angular/core and define the function openSnackBar (you can always use a different name).

Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SnackBarService {
  
//create an instance of MatSnackBar
  
  constructor(private snackBar:MatSnackBar) { }
  
/* It takes three parameters 
    1.the message string 
    2.the action 
    3.the duration, alignment, etc. */
  
  openSnackBar(message: string, action: string) {
    this.snackBar.open(message, action, {
       duration: 2000,
    });
  }
}
```

Import the snackBarService and inject it inside the constructor of the component, in which you want to use the Snackbar. This will create an instance of the service say snackBService.
Now call the openSnackBar function wherever it is required, with the help of snackBService.

Component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {SnackBarService} from '../snack.service';
  
  
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './snackBar.html',
  styleUrls: ['./snackBar.css']
})
export class SnackBar {
  
  // create an instance of SnackBarService 
  
  constructor(private snackBService:SnackBarService) { }
  
  //defining method for display of SnackBar
  
  trigger(message:string, action:string)
  {
   this.snackBService.openSnackBar(message, action);
  }
  
}
```

By repeating these steps we can use the snackBar inside any component.
Example:

```html
<button (click)="trigger('This is a ', 'SnackBar')">
    SnackBarButton
</button>
```

Comment: Looks really promising.  I'll give it a try.  Nevertheless, it looks like I need to put the snackBar service into every component.

Comment: Also, quick research suggests that this only works for Android.  Am I reading that correctly?  Will this work cross-platform?

Comment: I have developed a few PWA's where I've used snackbars on mobile devices. It works. Since Angular runs in the browser (it's not a native installable application) it will run on any OS. Though some browsers may have different compatibility for sure but I bet Angular team is working hard mitigate those chances. As for the snackbar service that is still true, that you need to inject snackBar service in each component where you plan to use it. OR you could daisy-chain events so that the snackBar will be triggered as a side effect to some action. But how you implement this is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for this.  In the end, I just build a simple popover.component and it was enough for my application.  But, your explanation was very clear, very helpful.  I'm going to mark it as the solution even though I went another way.